# Javascript - returning a subset of array members based on the existance of a value using Map or filter

Tags: javascript

I have had a look for this around SO  and whilst there is a lot of info on these concepts I am having trouble understanding how to bring all these ideas together to satisfy my problem.

I have an array:

```
[
  {
    route: ["", "scheduler"],
    name: "scheduler",
    settings: {
      icon: "user",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "left"
    },
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/scheduler/scheduler"),
    nav: true,
    title: "scheduler"
  },
  {
    route: "jobs",
    name: "jobs",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/jobs/jobsList"),
    settings: {
      icon: "list",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee"],
      pos: "left"
    },
    nav: true,
    title: "Jobs"
  },
  {
    route: "clients",
    name: "clients",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
    title: "Clients",
    nav: true,
    settings: {
      nav: [
        {
          icon: "list",
          route: "clients/ClientsList",
          name: "clientList",
          moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName(
            "../components/clients/clientList/clientList"
          ),
          href: "#clients/clientsList",
          title: "Client List",
          roles: ["Employee", "Admin"]
        },
        {
          icon: "user",
          route: "clients/create",
          name: "aboutTeam",
          moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName(
            "../components/clients/clientCreate/clientCreate"
          ),
          href: "#clients/Create",
          title: "Create Client",
          roles: ["Employee", "Admin"]
        }
      ],
      icon: "user",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "left"
    }
  },
  {
    route: "clients/ClientsList",
    name: "clientList",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientList/clientList"),
    settings: {
      icon: "list",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "left"
    }
  },
  {
    route: "clients/create",
    name: "aboutTeam",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/clients/clientCreate/clientCreate"),
    settings: {
      icon: "user",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "left"
    }
  },
  {
    route: "companyDetail",
    name: "companyDetail",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/administration/companyDetail/companyDetail"),
    settings: {
      icon: "list",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "left"
    },
    nav: true,
    title: "Company Detail"
  },
  {
    route: "user",
    name: "user",
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/administration/user/user"),
    settings: {
      icon: "user",
      auth: true,
      roles: ["Employee", "Admin"],
      pos: "right"
    },
    nav: true,
    title: "User"
  },
  {
    route: "notFound",
    name: "notFound",
    settings: { auth: false },
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("../components/notFound/notFound"),
    nav: false,
    title: "Not Found"
  }
]
```

Each one has a settings option in which there is an array of roles.

I wanted to loop through each array member to check if, say, the member was in the role of "Admin" and then add it to a new array using say "push".

However I am looking to learn JavaScript and extend my knowledge. I thought I would use the options of "map" and the "fat arrow" function to streamline the code so that I had a new array that contained all items where the roles contained a userRole of admin.

This is my attempt:

```
console.log(this.menu.map(r => r.filter(f => f.settings.roles === userRole)));
```

The full function is

```
public userMenu(userName: string, userRole: string): any {
const fullMenu = this.menuList();
console.log("userRole: ", userRole);
console.log(this.menu.map(r => r.filter(f => f.settings.roles === userRole)));
}
```

"userRole" exists and displays in the console but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

How do I structure the map function to work so that I return only those items that have "Admin" as part of the role array in the larger array above.

Comment: It appears that `this.menu` is not defined - what sets `this.menu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to loop through each array member to check if, say, the member was in the role of "Admin" and then add it to a new array using say "push".

The  [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions return new array so you do not need to create new array by yourself. If you need to loop through array, use `forEach` instead

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Please show your code that sets `this.menu`

`console.log(this.menu.map(r => r.filter(f => f.settings.roles === userRole)));`

- `map`, `filter` , `reduce` can only be used with array. The above code shown that you use `filter` against `r`, an object (as `menu` is an array of object)
- `f.settings.roles === userRole`: userRole is string but settings.roles is array so you must use `includes` (or `indexOf`) to use as condition of filter

As you only want to filter items that satisfy conditions, use `filter` is enough, like this

`menu.filter(r => r.settings.roles && r.settings.roles.includes('Admin'))`